# What is the English equivalent of the Russian saying "my ears are curling into tubes"?

Tags: word-choice, translation, russian

Background: 
Russians use this saying to describe extreme heat conditions in "Banya" when it is becoming almost unbearable.

Russian `Мои уши в трубочку сворачиваются?`

English literal translation `My ears are curling into tubes`

Question: 
What is English idiom that could be used in sauna or steam room to describe that it has gotten so hot, that it feels like your ears are curling into a tube?

Comment: Too long in damp/wet (bath?) - "I feel like I'm turning into a prune".

Comment: I thought word `prune` is associated with drying up and not with getting too wet or too hot?

Comment: @SaUce It's a reference to the fingers... See [here](http://www.livescience.com/26097-why-fingers-pruney-water.html).

Comment: Like @ElliottFrisch says - another link http://youtu.be/Hl5c1c_B3U8 - uses the idiom several times for what happens when (fingers/toes) are wet too long.

Comment: So is there anything other than `"I feel like I'm turning into a prune"` to describe sensation of your ears rolling up?

Comment: English doesn't have that precise idiom; maybe "I feel parboiled"?

Comment: Therefore if I say "It is so hot here that my ears are turning into prunes?" would that be understood?

Comment: "I'm pruning up" is a shorter alternate phrasing I've heard.  But regardless, you would not typically refer to the ears in such a situation - the reference is meant to be to the fingers or toes (you'd get odd looks if you said your ears were turning into prunes or your ears were pruning up).

Comment: First of all, that's actually an idiom meaning something like "listening to this is unbearable". Second of all, "мои уши в трубочьку заварачиваються" is not Russian. Russian would be "мои уши в трубочку заворачиваются". So what you have there is someone making fun of Russian in an untranslatable manner, or at least in a manner that can be mimicked in a great many ways, all of them equally correct.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I respect you comment but I would know better, I was born and raised there until I was 15. I have seen several Russian movies where same phrase is used in reference to extreme heat. Additionally I heard other Russians use it in same manner. And just because my spelling is not correct is not a reason to assume that I'm not Russian.

Comment: @RegDwigнt [here](http://www.kp.ru/daily/26177.5/3066778/) to Russian article where it is used in same manner. `- Тогда сами себя парили. Главным тут был Гиля Хусаинов. Заходит - парная битком. **Накидает воды на камни - так, что уши в трубочку сворачиваются**: «Татарин, ты что делаешь?!» Половина скатывается вниз. А они сядут и парятся.`

Comment: This is unclear. Are you asking about an English idiom for 'It's hot' or 'It's humid' or 'it's tropical' (hot -and- humid), or what @RegDwigнt said?

Comment: @Mitch is question clear enough now?

Comment: *So hot the hens are laying hard-boiled eggs.* and the *trees are whistling for the dogs*.

Comment: @SaUce: Basically your example illustrates meaning of "It's unbearable", I suspect that it's not generally related to heat or humidity even there. As a native speaker, I never heard this idiom used in extreme heat/humidity context, rather than "It's unbearable (to hear that)". It's common to use it referencing bad musicians, way too loud sources of noise, etc.

Comment: @GreyCat for when it is unbearable in regards to music or cursing, then we say "you make my ears to dry up" or "you make my ears to rot off". Even though curling into tubes can be used for that it is not the primary usage of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been in hot saunas and steam rooms and I've never thought that my ears are curling into tubes or heard an expression like it.

"It's *hotter than hell* here" is what folks might say.

In the UK they may say "It *ain't half hot* in here" for some unknown reason.

I've never heard Kris' "*so hot the hens are laying hard-boiled eggs*" but I like it.

Comment: I have heard "It's hotter than hell here" before, if no-one else submit any idioms I will accept that as answer. Any ideas if there any sayings that come from "sweat lodges" that might be more related to original setting?

Comment: Hotter than white man's hell? There probably are but i don't know.